# Function for simple navigation of dataframe in console

Tags: r

I was looking for a way to navigate through a dataframe in R using just the console that displays every n lines. There are a few functions you can find at StackOverflow that attempt to answer this but none are quite what I want. So I made my own function but it has a lot of `if` statements. How can I refactor my code to make it more concise and clean?

Note: I chose "." and "/" for page up and page down because code completion in RStudio automatically turns "[" into "[ ]". I'm open to any alternative symbols.

Here is the code. It is called "less" but it is obviously missing most of the functions in the Unix version of `less`.

```
less <- function(x, n = 10) {
  begin = 1
  end = n

  repeat {
    print(
      x[begin:end, ]
    )

    input <- readline("Type . to scroll up, type / to scroll down: ")

    if(input == ".") {
      begin = begin - n
      end = end - n
    }

    if(input == "/") {
      begin = begin + n
      end = end + n
    }

    if(end >= nrow(x)) break

    if(end < 1) break
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without changing the interface too much, your code could use the following changes. Note that I am fixing three bugs regarding corner cases:

1. if your data has fewer than `n` rows to start with (see where I used `min`)
2. if your data has a single column (see where I used `drop = FALSE`)
3. make sure that the last page will always show

I avoided duplicating the statements  where `begin` and `end` are reset, by creating an `increment` variable. The code computing the increment (of `+n` or `-n`) has been moved to its own function. One improvement I've made is that the function will call itself again via `Recall()` in case the user entered something other than the expected `.` or `/`, i.e. it will prompt the user again.

```
less <- function(x, n = 10) {
  begin <- 1
  end   <- n

  get_increment <- function() {
    input <- readline("Type . to scroll up, type / to scroll down: ")
    if (input == ".") -n else if (input == "/") +n else Recall()
  }

  repeat {
    print(x[begin:min(end, nrow(x)), , drop = FALSE])

    increment <- get_increment()
    begin     <- begin + increment
    end       <- end   + increment

    if(begin > nrow(x) | end < 1) break
  }
}
```

Now regarding your design in general, I feel it would be nice to pre-split your data.frame every `n` rows, and let the user know that there are for example 12 pages and that he is currently looking at page 4/12. In the prompt, also allow the user to jump to a specific page in addition to the next or previous page. Finally, make it easier to exit via a specific code like `"q"` rather than wait for the user to go beyond the first or last page. Here is my attempt:

```
less <- function(x, n = 10) {

   N <- nrow(x)
   if (N == 0) {
      message("input has no rows")
      return(NULL)
   }

   row_page_idx <- (seq_len(N) - 1) %/% n
   pages <- split(x, row_page_idx)
   num_pages <- length(pages)
   page_idx <- 1

   get_new_page_idx <- function() {
      input <- readline('Type a page number, ">" for next, "<" for previous, or "q" to quit: ')
      if (input == "q") return(0)
      if (input == ">") return(min(num_pages, page_idx + 1))
      if (input == "<") return(max(1, page_idx - 1))
      integer <- suppressWarnings(as.integer(input))
      if (!is.na(integer) & integer %in% 1:num_pages) return(integer)
      Recall() # if all fails
   }

   repeat {
      print(pages[[page_idx]])
      message("Page ", page_idx, " of ", num_pages)
      page_idx <- get_new_page_idx()
      if(page_idx == 0) break
   }
}
```

Comment: How does `suppressWarnings` work here? If I just type, for example, `as.integer(^)` I get an error. So if the input is an unexpected symbol, why doesn't that cause an error?

Comment: My `input` object has to be a string since it is the output of calling`readline()`. So you probably meant to test `as.integer("^")`. See that it returns `NA` with a warning. `suppressWarnings` will remove that warning.

Answer (score 2):

#### Reinventing the wheel

This kind of functionality already exists in the `page` function, for example if you run this on the console:

```
page(cars, method=c('print'))
```

This will show the `cars` object in a pager just like the `less` command in UNIX. You can scroll up and down using naturally the arrow keys, and it even supports a wide range of the same keyboard shortcuts to skip screens (`space`), half-screens (`d`, `u`), jump to beginning or end (`g`, `G`), and exit anytime (`q`).

Inside RStudio, `page` works a bit differently. It opens a new tab with all of the content at once. That might not be the way you want, indeed.

#### Bugs

Be careful with corner cases, as @flodel already pointed out.
In fact there were so many bugs he missed one:
the last page will never be shown, for example:

```
less(head(cars, n=20))
```

This will show only one page, with the first 10 items, if you try to scroll down with `/` the function exits without showing anything.

#### Alternative implementation

The `start` and `end` variables are modified independently,
but they are tightly related:
`start` should be the previous `end` + 1,
and `end` should be the next `start` - 1.
This relationship is not expressed directly in the code,
which could lead to accidents.
For example, you might change the code setting the value of `start`,
and forget to make the similar change to `end`.

An alternative approach that would solve this could be pre-calculating the start values into a vector,
and track a single index pointing to the current start value in this vector.
That is, the start is the value at the index,
and the end is the value at [index+1] - 1.

```
less <- function(x, n = 10) {
  intervals <- c(seq(1, nrow(x), by=n), nrow(x) + 1)
  index <- 1

  next_index <- function() {
    input <- readline("Type . to scroll up, type / to scroll down: ")
    if (input == ".") index - 1
    else if (input == "/") index + 1
    else Recall()
  }

  repeat {
    start <- intervals[index]
    end <- intervals[index + 1] - 1
    print(x[start:end, , drop = FALSE])

    if (length(intervals) -1 <= index) break

    index <- next_index()

    if (index < 1) break
  }
}
```

#### Usability

`/` and `.` seems unusual as navigation shortcuts.
How about `d` and `u` instead, for "down" and "up"?
Or, though this might get too geeky,
but many software use `j` and `k` for vertical navigation.

Comment: This is an interesting lesson for me. The way I designed this was to look at specifically one type of dataframe that my data typically comes in and I wasn't thinking about passing other functions like `head` to it. My testcases were basically just the kind of dataframe/layouts that I needed at the time. I know books have probably been written on this subject but: How does one write a function properly to think of all the corner cases and things a user might try to do when there are so many options out there?

Comment: You are correct: In RStudio the `page` doesn't act the way I wanted.

Comment: How to think of all corner cases... I don't know, I just try to break stuff, it's fun :) The fact that I'm using `head` is irrelevant. I could have passed any data frame with 20 rows. I used 3 kinds of test cases, with row count less than `n`, equal to a multiple of `n`, or greater than `n` and not a multiple. Instead of creating multiple data frames, I used the stock `cars` data frame and `head` to control the row count. That's all.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your help! I appreciate all your improvements, I've learned a lot from this.